# Como hacer un array que sea un contador

Tags: array, contador

Debo mediante un array de 1*8 crear un contador que vaya de 00000000 a 77777777 pero cada que un digito llegue a 7 se reinicie y aumente uno al de su izquierda

Comment: Especifica el lenguaje, pon el codigo q has intentado y pon un ejemplo minimo verificable

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.